with llncs.cls, using babel turns compression of bibliographic references off, and dropping babel turns it on
Feeding
\documentclass{llncs}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\cite{A,B,C}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{A}A
\bibitem{B}B
\bibitem{C}C
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

to latex to pdflatex yields the references

[1-3]

Notice that the list of references is represented as an interval. Using the package babel yields, on the contrary, the list fully spelled out:

[1,2,3]


Why the difference?

How to turn the range compression on with babel? I found no option compressed in the manuals of babel and llncs.



With the option safe=none, ie, \usepackage[safe=none]{babel}. Note with it you cannot use shorthands in bib labels.

@JavierBezos Works like a charm for the MWE. Thank you!

@JavierBezos Can you convert your comment into an answer please? Thank you.

By default, babel redefines some macros related to cross references and bibliographies for they to allow shorthands in labels. Sadly, this change may interfere with other packages, so an option to leave them unchanged is provided:
\usepackage[safe=none]{babel}

There is a little price to pay, namely, shorthands can raise an error if used in labels.
